# Probability with a non-union distribution

Tags: probability

Find the probability that the first child of a family with five children is a boy or that the last two children of the family are girls if the probability of a boy is .51

Right now, I believe I am semi-on track with the thinking that in order to find this probability, you need to find $P(E)-P(F)-P(E \cup F)$.

If I am correct $P(E) = .51$

However, I am unsure on how to find $P(F)$ and $P(E \cup F)$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find: $\mathsf P(\textrm{First child is a boy OR last two children are girls}) = \mathsf P(E\cup F) \\ = \mathsf P(E)+\mathsf P(F)-\mathsf P(E\cap F)$

You have correctly determined that $\mathsf P(E)=0.51$, the probability of the first child being a boy.

Then likewise the probability that the last child is a girl is $0.49$ and the probability that the second last child is a girl is also $0.49$ and these are independent events so then the probability that they are both girls is: $\mathsf P(F)=...$

And similarly the probability that all three are, in order, a boy, a girl, and a girl is: $\mathsf P(E\cap F)$